# Customizing AntRunner output

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-pde, antrunner

I'm using Eclipse's AntRunner to build a set of plugins, but I'm having trouble in configuring the logging behavior. Specifically, I'd like AntRunner not to display empty tasks. Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to pass the following JVM options:

```
java -jar ... -logger org.apache.tools.ant.NoBannerLogger
```