# Eclipse ant build gives "Another singleton version selected", how can I stop that?

Tags: eclipse, ant

We run org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner to build our plugins and RCP projects. In the build logs we get a ton of messages like:

```
[eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.X:  
[eclipse.buildScript]   Another singleton version selected: org.eclipse.equinox.X_1.0.4.v20081112-1019
```

The reason is clear; There are two different versions of a particular bundle and it chose the latest. We cannot change the Eclipse installation to remove the older plugins, so what can be done to get rid of these messages?

Bonusquestion: What class prints out these messages? One option could be to create our own version where these messages are never shown.

*Edit*:
Stackoverflow suggested this question:
[Customizing AntRunner output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148641/customizing-antrunner-output)
From there I found this page:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html
which contains more info of ant logger and listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in Eclipse 3.5, the messages can be turned off by setting `suppressResolutionErrors=true` in your build configuration build.properties file.  (This was actually added to [speed up the unit tests](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=274834).)

The messages are printed in `org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.BuildTimeSite#getRegistry()`

Comment: Thanks. We are using 3.4, so that doesn't help me directly. However if its fixed in 3.5 I guess we can live with for now.

Comment: We are using E3.6.1 now with the suppressResolutionErrors=true, but are still getting the warning messages. 
I see that bug is still in state new, so it hasn't been released?